# How do I differentiate between an enum's name from enum index items?

Tags: enums, terminology

I'm having a terrible time communicating with my teammates when I talk about enums. I can never properly differentiate what part of the enum I'm talking about.

```
enum PowerLevel {
    Low,
    Medium,
    High
}
```

`Low`, `Medium`, and `High` are what part of the enum?

What part is `PowerLevel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say that "Powerlevels" is the name of the enumeration.  "Low", "Medium" and "High" are the members of the enumeration.  These are also sometimes called named constants or elements.

This page actually uses all three names:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is powerlevels. It has three different values/instances : low, medium and high.

Low is an instance of powerlevels and is guaranteed to be a singleton.